# Rsync unexpectedly closed

Tags: linux, rsync

I have this backup script that runs on about 100 clients and normally works fine.
Now I have at problem with 1 client that normally don't have any issues

This is the line that normally runs fine.

```
rsync -z --partial --times  -vvvvv --recursive --log-file="/backup/clientx/clientx.debug-star2.log" --rsync-path="nice -n19 ionice -c3  rsync" --timeout=3600 --delete-after --bwlimit=500 --rsh "nice -n19 ionice -c3  ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i /root/.ssh/clientx_rsync_id_rsa" /backup/clientx/dir1/ backup@remote-server:/backup/clientx/dir1
```

And it starts up fine and starts to build the file list.

```
note: iconv_open("UTF-8", "UTF-8") succeeded.
(Client) Protocol versions: remote=30, negotiated=30
building file list ...
[sender] change_dir(/backup/clinetx/dir1)
[sender] make_file(.,*,0)
[sender] make_file(inc,*,2)
[sender] make_file(clientx.log,*,2)
[sender] make_file(full,*,2)
[sender] make_file(inc/2015,*,2)
[sender] make_file(inc/2007,*,2)
[sender] make_file(inc/2012,*,2)
```

But it stops, not building the the file list and exit with this.

```
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (9 bytes received so far) [sender]
[sender] _exit_cleanup(code=12, file=io.c, line=601): entered
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(601) [sender=3.0.7]
[sender] _exit_cleanup(code=12, file=io.c, line=601): about to call exit(255)
```

But if I try the same on another directory it's fine.
The only difference is the `dir2` have about 1600 files and `dir1` have about 4300 files.

And as I said, it runs fine on all the other clients, with the same amount of files.

```
ls -ld
dir1 - drwxrwx--- 4 root nagios 4096 May 23 20:59 .
dir2 - drwxrwx--- 7 root nagios 4096 Feb 22  2016 .
```

Anyone have an idea of what goes wrong?

Comment: Nothing leaps out at me. This same line works if you replace `dir1` with `dir2`? What's different about these two directories locally _and_ on the remote? Perhaps [edit] your question with the result of `ls -ld dir1 dir2` on both ends.

Comment: Any disk-related issues on that host? `fsck` that partition?

Comment: Read your logs. If the connection is being terminated abnormally, something should be logging why. Likely the ssh daemon on the remote end.

Comment: Roaima:
I just added the ls -ld output on both dirs

Comment: kusalananda: the partition is fine

Comment: Patrick: i'll have another go on the logs, nothing to see at first glans.

Answer (score 1):

Same situation here: a venerable backup script works everywhere EXCEPT for hosts at a single remote site where the ISP is AT&T fiber service; the modem there is an Arris.  It always works for a VERY short time (< 2 seconds) and then the connection is abruptly terminated.

Alas, my darkest suspicion proved true.  By trial and error, using different values for the rsync "--bwlimit" parameter, I discovered that the connection is not interrupted with "--bwlimit=56" or less, but it is *always* interrupted with "--bwlimit=57" or more.

At the remote site, I looked through the Arris modem's user interface at 192.168.1.254 and found nothing to adjust.  All ports are forwarded through it to the OpenWRT 18.06 router there ("DMZplus mode").  The router is the same one, having very similar settings, as several other routers at several other sites, none of which have this connection interruption problem.

Limiting communications to 56 Kbytes/sec is a terrible solution, but at least it's a solution that actually seems to work.  Appalling, really.  Beware AT&T.  (Which enjoys a monopoly position at this particular remote location.)

Comment: This is unbelievable.  Surely this answer must be from 1992!

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to backup to a remote system with id `backup` but the permissions on the remote system preclude that account from accessing the target directories.

You will need either to relax the permissions so that user `backup` can write to `dir1` and `dir2` or else use the `root` account as your target user.

Comment: The permissions haven't changed, and the user backup can access both dirs, there have been no change to the system, and i tryed this morning to change permissions but without luck.
The only change is that the costumer have changed firewall "nothing that i have access to", but then both backup jobs should go down the drain and not just dir1

Comment: @bmh is `backup` a user account with UID 0? Or is it  a member of the `nagios` group? Otherwise it cannot write to the directories you've listed.